# Rails_admin - How to set default 'add filter' match type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have searched and read a lot but I can't find any hints on how to do this.

When I 'add filter' per the picture below the default match is `...` which does nothing. See picture below.

I want to set the default matching to `contains`. I want `contains` to be showing and be used with no initial user interaction. If they want to change it from `contains` - they can. It will be the default though rather than `...`

Can someone point to docs or tell me how to do that?

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I didn't add any code to do this. This `add filter` menu comes with Rails_admin out of the box.

Comment: I see that the [User list](https://rails-admin-tb.herokuapp.com/admin/user) of the [Rails Admin Dummy App](https://rails-admin-tb.herokuapp.com/admin/) already has this feature – when you go to the “Add filter” menu and choose “Email”, the default filter type is “Contains”. Maybe you can see why this happens from the demo app’s [source code](https://github.com/bbenezech/dummy_app).

Comment: Are the fields you are adding filter for strings? If they are not strings, it makes sense that you couldn't do a “Contains” filter on them, though it wouldn’t explain why they don’t default to another filter type.

Comment: Thanks @RoryO'Kane, My fields are strings. I will look at that Rails Admin Dummy App.